# Resize text as rectangle Resizes in Canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am new to Canvas, I am creating a website to increase text as I re-sizes rectangle.I tried so much but nothing works for me. Actually I want if I re size rectangle just by its width( stretch To Left /To Right), only text width should be increased not the fontsize. I have done with fontsize but finding difficulty in increasing isolated Text Height and Width. your suggestions are most welcome

[image]

```
function Box2() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.w = 1; // default width and height?
        this.h = 1;
        this.fill = '#CC0000';
        this.Owntext = "";
        this.fontsize = '20';
        this.TextColor = '';
        this.TextFontFamily = '';
        this.Angle = 0;
        this.ScaleHeight = 1;
        this.ScaleWidth = 1;
    }

    // New methods on the Box class
    Box2.prototype = {
        // we used to have a solo draw function
        // but now each box is responsible for its own drawing
        // mainDraw() will call this with the normal canvas
        // myDown will call this with the ghost canvas with 'black'
        draw: function (context, optionalColor) {
            if (context === gctx) {
                context.fillStyle = 'black'; // always want black for the ghost canvas
            } else {
                context.fillStyle = this.fill;
            }
       //     alert('Box2.prototype');
            // We can skip the drawing of elements that have moved off the screen:
            if (this.x > WIDTH || this.y > HEIGHT) return;
            if (this.x + this.w < 0 || this.y + this.h < 0) return;

            context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);

            // draw selection
            // this is a stroke along the box and also 8 new selection handles
            if (mySel === this) {
                context.strokeStyle = mySelColor;
                context.lineWidth = mySelWidth;
                context.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);

                // draw the boxes

                var half = mySelBoxSize / 2;

                // 0  1  2
                // 3     4
                // 5  6  7

                // top left, middle, right
                selectionHandles[0].x = this.x - half;
                selectionHandles[0].y = this.y - half;

                selectionHandles[1].x = this.x + this.w / 2 - half;
                selectionHandles[1].y = this.y - half;

                selectionHandles[2].x = this.x + this.w - half;
                selectionHandles[2].y = this.y - half;

                //middle left
                selectionHandles[3].x = this.x - half;
                selectionHandles[3].y = this.y + this.h / 2 - half;

                //middle right
                selectionHandles[4].x = this.x + this.w - half;
                selectionHandles[4].y = this.y + this.h / 2 - half;

                //bottom left, middle, right
                selectionHandles[6].x = this.x + this.w / 2 - half;
                selectionHandles[6].y = this.y + this.h - half;

                selectionHandles[5].x = this.x - half;
                selectionHandles[5].y = this.y + this.h - half;

                selectionHandles[7].x = this.x + this.w - half;
                selectionHandles[7].y = this.y + this.h - half;


                context.fillStyle = mySelBoxColor;
                for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    var cur = selectionHandles[i];
                    context.fillRect(cur.x, cur.y, mySelBoxSize, mySelBoxSize);
                }
            }

        } // end draw

    }

    //Initialize a new Box, add it, and invalidate the canvas
    function addRect(x, y, w, h, fill,text,FontSize,TextColor,TextFontFamily,Angle,ScaleWidth,ScaleHeight) {
        var rect = new Box2;
        rect.x = x;
        rect.y = y;
        rect.w = w
        rect.h = h;
        rect.Owntext = text;
        rect.FontSize = FontSize;
        rect.TextColor = TextColor;
        rect.TextFontFamily = TextFontFamily;
        rect.Angle = Angle;
        rect.ScaleWidth = ScaleWidth;
        rect.ScaleHeight = ScaleHeight;
       // alert(TextFontFamily);
      //  rect.fontsize = FontSize;

      //  alert(fill);

        rect.fill = fill;
        boxes2.push(rect);
        invalidate();
    }
    var CanvasHeight = 0;
    var CanvasWidth = 0;
    // initialize our canvas, add a ghost canvas, set draw loop
    // then add everything we want to intially exist on the canvas
    function init2() {
        //   alert('init2')
        dropdownTextFamily = document.getElementById('drpFontFamily');
        dropdown = document.getElementById('drpTextColor');
        Button = document.getElementById('Mybtn');
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');
        HEIGHT = canvas.height;
        WIDTH = canvas.width;
       // CanvasHeight=
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ghostcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        ghostcanvas.height = HEIGHT;
        ghostcanvas.width = WIDTH;
        gctx = ghostcanvas.getContext('2d');

        //fixes a problem where double clicking causes text to get selected on the canvas
        canvas.onselectstart = function () { return false; }

        // fixes mouse co-ordinate problems when there's a border or padding
        // see getMouse for more detail
        if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
            stylePaddingLeft = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['paddingLeft'], 10) || 0;
            stylePaddingTop = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['paddingTop'], 10) || 0;
            styleBorderLeft = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['borderLeftWidth'], 10) || 0;
            styleBorderTop = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(canvas, null)['borderTopWidth'], 10) || 0;
        }

        // make mainDraw() fire every INTERVAL milliseconds
        setInterval(mainDraw, INTERVAL);

        // set our events. Up and down are for dragging,
        // double click is for making new boxes
        canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
        canvas.onmouseup = myUp;
        Button.onclick = myDblClickButton;
        dropdown.onchange = ChangeTextColor;
        dropdownTextFamily.onchange = ChangeTextFontFamily;
       // lblCheck.onclick = myclick;
       // textBox.onkeyup = myDblClick;
        //  canvas.ondblclick = myDblClick;
     //   alert('ethe');
        canvas.onmousemove = myMove;

        // set up the selection handle boxes
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
          //  alert();
            var rect = new Box2;
            selectionHandles.push(rect);//WATCHED ******* A New Reactangle Added To The Canvas 
        }















        // add custom initialization here:


        // add a large green rectangle
     //   addRect(260, 70, 60, 65, 'rgba(0,205,0,0.7)');

        // add a green-blue rectangle
      //  addRect(240, 120, 40, 40, 'rgba(2,165,165,0.7)');

        // add a smaller purple rectangle
        //  addRect(45, 60, 25, 25, 'rgba(150,150,250,0.7)');


        // get a reference to the canvas element, and its context



        var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
        var ctx1 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

        // sets maximum line width, line height, and x /y coords for text

        var maxWidth = canvas2.width - 10;
        var lineHeight = 23;
        var x_pos = (canvas2.width - maxWidth) / 2;
        var y_pos = 15;
        var DbClickCount=0;
        // register onkeyup event for #text_cnv text field to add the text in canvas as it is typed
        document.getElementById('textBox').onkeyup = function () {
          //  clearCanvas(canvas2);      // clears the canvas
            //alert(ctx1);
            // mySel.Owntext = this.value;
             //alert(mySel.w);

            if (mySel == null) {
                // alert('I am Here');

                myDblClick();
                var x = 10;
                var y = 10;
             //   alert(x);
                myDown1(x, y);
                addTextCnv(ctx1, this.value, mySel.x, mySel.y, mySel.h, mySel.w);
               // addTextCnv(ctx1, this.value, 260, 120, 60, 65);
              //  myDown1();
               // mySel.x = 260;
               // mySel.y = 100;
               // myDown1(260,100);
                // mySel.h = 50;
               // mySel.w = 5;
               // addTextCnv(ctx1, this.value, 260, 100, 50, 5);
               //// addTextCnv(ctx1, this.value, mySel.x, mySel.y, mySel.h, mySel.w);
            }
            else
            {
                // addTextCnv(ctx1, this.value, 260, 120, 60, 65);
              //  alert(mySel.x);
               // alert(mySel.y);
              //  alert(mySel.h);
              //  alert(mySel.w);
                addTextCnv(ctx1, this.value, mySel.x, mySel.y, mySel.h, lineHeight);
            }

            //alert(mySel.x);
            //addTextCnv(ctx1, this.value, 260, 120, 60, 65);
          //  mainDraw(this.value);
          //alert(this.value);
          //addTextCnv(ctx1, this.value, x_pos, y_pos, maxWidth, 23);
        }
        var text2 = "Sachdeva";
       // document.write("<p>Fontsize: " + text2.fontsize(6) + "</p>");
       //  text2.fontsize(6);
              //alert(mySel.Owntext);
        //  ctx1.font = 'italic 20px Calibri';
        ctx1.font = '20pt Calibri';
        //TextFontFamily

        var text1 = "rajay";
      //  var text3 = "rajay1";

   //     addRect(260, 70, 60, 15, 'rgba(0,205,0,0.7)',text1);

        // add a smaller purple rectangle
      //  alert('hi');
   //     addRect(45, 60, 25, 15, 'rgba(150,150,250,0.7)', text2);
        //addRect(260, 85, 60, 65, 'rgba(0,205,0,0.7)', text3);






    }


function myMove(e) {


   ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (isDrag) {
       // alert('hi');
        getMouse(e);
      //  alert(e.x);
      //   alert('drag');
        mySel.x = mx - offsetx;
     //   alert(mySel.x);
        mySel.y = my - offsety;

        // something is changing position so we better invalidate the canvas!
        invalidate();
    } else if (isResizeDrag) {
       // alert('hi');
        // time ro resize!
        getMouse(e);
        var oldx = mySel.x;
        var oldy = mySel.y;
        var oldw = mySel.w;
        var oldh = mySel.h;
        //alert(mySel.h);
        //alert(expectResize)
        switch (expectResize) {
            case 0:

              // mySel.x = mx;
               // mySel.y = my;
               // mySel.w += oldx - mx;
             //   mySel.h += oldy - my;
             //   mySel.ScaleWidth = 2;
            //    mySel.ScaleHeight = 1;
           //     alert(mySel.w);
              //  mySel.FontSize = (mySel.h/2)+(mySel.w/4);
              //  alert(mySel.FontSize);
               // alert(mySel.h);
               // alert(mySel.w);
             //   alert(mySel.Angle);
               // var clickAngle = getAngle(mySel.x, mySel.y, mx, my) - mySel.Angle;
                //alert(clickAngle);
              //var clickAngle = getAngle(cX + offX, cY + offY, event.clientX, event.clientY) - model.angle;
              //  mySel.Angle = (getAngle(mySel.x, mySel.y, mx, my) - clickAngle);
              //  alert(mySel.Angle);
             //   mySel.Angle = 45;

               // alert(mySel.Angle);
               // alert(mySel.h);


            //    ctx.font = 'italic ' + (2 / 3) * mySel.h + 'px' + ' Calibri';
               // ctx.font = 'italic ' + (2 / 3) * mySel.h+'px' + ' Calibri';
               // alert(ctx.font);
                break;
            case 1:
                mySel.y = my;
                mySel.h += oldy - my;
          //      alert(mySel.h);
                if (mySel.FontSize>mySel.h){
                    mySel.FontSize = mySel.h;
                }
                else
                {
                   // alert('Hi');
                    mySel.FontSize = mySel.FontSize;
                }
               // mySel.FontSize = (mySel.h / 2) + (mySel.w / 4);
              //  ctx.scale(1, 2);
              //  ctx.font = 'italic ' + (2 / 3) * mySel.h + 'px' + ' Calibri';
                break;
            case 2:
                mySel.y = my;
                mySel.w = mx - oldx;
                mySel.h += oldy - my;
                mySel.FontSize = (mySel.h / 2) + (mySel.w / 4);
          //      ctx.font = 'italic ' + (2 / 3) * mySel.h + 'px' + ' Calibri';
                break;
            case 3:
                mySel.x = mx;
                mySel.w += oldx - mx;
                mySel.FontSize = (mySel.h / 2) + (mySel.w / 4);
                break;
            case 4:
                mySel.w = mx - oldx;
               // mySel.FontSize = mySel.FontSize;
                mySel.FontSize = (mySel.h / 2) + (mySel.w / 4);
                break;
            case 5:
                mySel.x = mx;
                mySel.w += oldx - mx;
                mySel.h = my - oldy;
                mySel.FontSize = (mySel.h / 2) + (mySel.w / 4);
        //        ctx.font = 'italic ' + (2 / 3) * mySel.h + 'px' + ' Calibri';
                break;
            case 6:
                //mySel.h = my - oldy;
                //mySel.FontSize = mySel.h;
        //        ctx.font = 'italic ' + (2 / 3) * mySel.h + 'px' + ' Calibri';
                break;
            case 7:
                mySel.w = mx - oldx;
                mySel.h = my - oldy;
                mySel.FontSize = (mySel.h / 2) + (mySel.w / 4);
        //        ctx.font = 'italic ' + (2 / 3) * mySel.h + 'px' + ' Calibri';
                break;
        }
       // alert(mySel.FontSize);
        invalidate();
    }

    getMouse(e);
    // if there's a selection see if we grabbed one of the selection handles
    if (mySel !== null && !isResizeDrag) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            // 0  1  2
            // 3     4
            // 5  6  7

            var cur = selectionHandles[i];

         //   alert('Here');
            // we dont need to use the ghost context because
            // selection handles will always be rectangles
            if (mx >= cur.x && mx <= cur.x + mySelBoxSize &&
                my >= cur.y && my <= cur.y + mySelBoxSize) {
                // we found one!
                expectResize = i;
                invalidate();

                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        this.style.cursor = 'nw-resize';
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        this.style.cursor = 'n-resize';
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        this.style.cursor = 'ne-resize';
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        this.style.cursor = 'w-resize';
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        this.style.cursor = 'e-resize';
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        this.style.cursor = 'sw-resize';
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        this.style.cursor = 's-resize';
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        this.style.cursor = 'se-resize';
                        break;
                }
                return;
            }

        }
        // not over a selection box, return to normal
        isResizeDrag = false;
        expectResize = -1;
        this.style.cursor = 'auto';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to perform some computation to have the bounding box of the text, then use **scale** on the context to have it match the rect you want to fill.
You get the width of a text by using **measureText**. Unfortunately, only the text width is provided, but the height value is always close from the fontSize.

```js
var cv = document.getElementById('cv');
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');

function drawTextInBox(txt, font, x, y, w, h, angle) {
  angle = angle || 0;
  var fontHeight = 20;
  var hMargin = 4;
  ctx.font = fontHeight + 'px ' + font;
  ctx.textAlign = 'left';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
  var txtWidth = ctx.measureText(txt).width + 2 * hMargin;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(x+w/2, y);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.strokeRect(-w/2, 0, w, h);
  ctx.scale(w / txtWidth, h / fontHeight);
  ctx.translate(hMargin, 0)
  ctx.fillText(txt, -txtWidth/2, 0);
  ctx.restore();
}

drawTextInBox('This is a line', 'Arial', 2, 2, 60, 20);

drawTextInBox('Another line here', 'Arial', 2, 32, 160, 40, 0.1);

drawTextInBox('The Last line', 'Arial', 2, 82, 220, 90);

drawTextInBox('! Now with an angle !', 'Arial', 42, 190, 120, 30, -Math.PI/12);
```

```html
<canvas width=400 height=300 id='cv'></canvas>
```

Comment: Lot of thanks for such a great code. I really appretiate your help. I need one more favor from you. Can we rotate the text/Rectangle by their end points?

Comment: You're welcome. By end point i understand the rotation axe is the right-most/vertically centered point.  Are you sure you don't prefer the rotation to be centered (middle in both horizontal and vertical direction) ?

Comment: By The End Points I Mean Only Corners Of A Rectangle. At MouseDown Event, I want when I click on any corner of rectangle and try to rotate(Drag in circular), it should change the rotate anticlockwise/clockwise.