# Adding Editable text box to canvas element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events

I have an HTML page that allows a person to draw. Its very simple. The code for It is included down below.

I'm trying to add a button that inserts text that is editable and can be resized within the canvas element.

I have tried many options, but found no success. Is there a way to do that in Javascript?

The code I have:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        Web Paint!
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        #draw{
            border-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="hex" placeholder="enter hex color"></input>
    <canvas id="draw"></canvas>

    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("draw");

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        //resize();

        // resize canvas when window is resized
        function resize() {
        ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        }

        // initialize position as 0,0
        var pos = { x: 0, y: 0 };

        // new position from mouse events
        function setPosition(e) {
        pos.x = e.clientX-160;
        pos.y = e.clientY-5;
        }

        function draw(e) {
        if (e.buttons !== 1) return; // if mouse is not clicked, do not go further

        var color = document.getElementById("hex").value;

        ctx.beginPath(); // begin the drawing path

        ctx.lineWidth = 20; // width of line
        ctx.lineCap = "round"; // rounded end cap
        ctx.strokeStyle = color; // hex color of line

        ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y); // from position
        setPosition(e);
        ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y); // to position

        ctx.stroke(); // draw it!
        }

        // add window event listener to trigger when window is resized
        window.addEventListener("resize", resize);

        // add event listeners to trigger on different mouse events
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
        document.addEventListener("mousedown", setPosition);
        document.addEventListener("mouseenter", setPosition);


    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do above codes do or in your code, where you are having the issue? And exactly what you tried so far to solve the problem? And moreover, can you give us a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: The above code is just basically a canvas element with some js code that makes you able to draw on it as you move your mouse. I have tried adding text elements to the canvas element and make it editable but it doesn't work. I'm not really that experienced with javascript. This is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=qlN2tUN7aQ    , you can draw by clicking and moving the mouse over to the small box next to the hex code text field.

Comment: When I click on your link, it gives empty blank fiddle. Are you sure this is the correct link for the fiddle? Did you save your fiddle?

Comment: Oh my bad. See if this will work: https://jsfiddle.net/uk7bpzcs/1/#&togetherjs=uO8azNihiQ

Comment: Did you try this one [**Resize text as rectangle Resizes in Canvas HTML5**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26437176/resize-text-as-rectangle-resizes-in-canvas-html5)?